# How to send/receive data in avro format from jersey?

Tags: json, performance, protocol-buffers, jersey-2.0, avro

I have a set of web services developed using `jersey` and currently web services send and receive data in `JSON` format. To improve performance both in terms of processing time and memory required, we are experimenting with `Protobuf` and `avro`.

I found some tutorials which show how easy it is to integrate `protobuf` into such web service. But I am not able to find such a tutorial or any book which will give atleast some idea about whether we can send/receive data in `avro` format using `jersey`.

I would like to know how to send/receive data in `avro` format using `jersey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar issue, and I'm surprised nobody else has had a solution in two years.  We're using Jersey 2.x, and I used a `Provider` to handle Avro.

This snippet works if you generate the code.  If you don't, you have to use the
`GenericDatumReader/Writer` and `GenericRecord` instead of the `SpecificDataReader/Writer` and `SpecificRecord`.

Also take note that the Avro spec says to use `avro/binary` as the content type, although there is a 6-year-old [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-488) to change it since it is an invalid type.

I stripped this down to make it simple, so there is no error handling in it.  Be careful if you have a common `ExceptionMapper` that catches general exceptions as it won't know how to produce avro binary.

```
@Provider
@Consumes("avro/binary")
@Produces("avro/binary")
public class AvroProvider <T extends SpecificRecord> implements MessageBodyWriter<T>, MessageBodyReader<T>
{
    public boolean isWriteable(final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations,
            final MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return SpecificRecord.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    public boolean isReadable(final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations,
            final MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
        DatumReader<T> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(type);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(entityStream, null);
        return reader.read(null, decoder);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void writeTo(T message, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
      DatumWriter<T> datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<>((Class<T>)type);
      Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(entityStream, null);
      datumWriter.write(message, encoder);
      encoder.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(T message, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return -1;
    }

}
```